# Managing files and directories in an app's Documents directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdocumentdirectory

I am trying to work out how to manage files and directories in my app's **Documents** folder. I have been trying to make sense of the NSData class but without joy. I have managed to write an image to my **Documents** folder using the following code.

```
- (IBAction)writeImage:(id)sender
{
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedImage.png"];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];
}
```

What I would like to know is how to create and delete directories and files. Can anyone point me to correct place to look? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, `NSFileManager`.

Answer (score 1):

For folder you can use:

```
 [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtURL:folder withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
```

It will create all folders at given path which is cool :)

Answer (score 1):

The [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class enables you to perform many generic file-system operations and insulates an app from the underlying file system.

There is a class method in `NSFileManager` class called `+defaultManager` which always gives you same `FileManager` object or shared Object and most file operations can be performed using this shared file manager object.

Answer (score 0):

You can write by avoiding overwriting your file if it already exists as below and can also check if the folder is writable or not.

```
NSString *imageName = @"Default.png";
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *savedImagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectoryPath, imageName];

// Write only if file does not exist.
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savedImagePath]) {
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];
}


// Check if folder is writable
NSString *folderPath = @"someFolderPath";
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] isWritableFileAtPath:folderPath]) {
    NSLog(@"Folder is writable");
}else {
    NSLog(@"Folder is not writable");
}
```